# Count if a cell is not blank, and matches an adjacent cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Example table

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| First | First |
| Second | Second |
| Third | Third |
|  | Fourth |
| Fifth | Fifth |
| Sixth |  |

So, what I am trying to do is Count all the cells in column 1 that are NOT blank AND match the adjacent cell in Column 2.

In this case, the total count should be 4. How would this formula be written?

Comment: Something like `=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A7=B2:B7)*(A2:A7<>""))`

Comment: If they match then you don't need to check for blank.

Comment: @SolarMike Why not?

Comment: @JvdV first = first, but "" <> fourth...

Comment: @SolarMike but empty = empty = true

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A7=B2:B7)*(A2:A7<>"")
```

Comment: You're missing a `)`